# uim can’t register mozc (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, input-method

Trying to use mozc with uim, I installed

```
apt-get install uim-utils mozc-utils-gui uim-gtk3
```

(`mozc-server` automatically installed) and following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mozc#uim) suggestion, further ran

```
sudo uim-module-manager --register mozc
```

but it says

```
Warning: Module mozc is not a correct module.
```

and uim-pref-gtk3 app still doesn’t list mozc in either the enabled or disabled input methods list.

I’m doing all this on Gallium OS 2.1 which is based on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: mozc officially supports only ibus, so the special `uim-mozc` package is needed providing the additional `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/uim/plugin/libuim-mozc.so` file. While the Arch wiki page refers to the [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/uim-mozc/), for Ubuntu [it’s available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/uim-mozc) only in trusty or after zesty. The solution would be to install it from one of those other releases.

Some dependency issues are still hindering me in installing it from trusty and the one from zesty has some runtime libprotobuf version issues.

Comment: Installing `uim-mozc` does work if you first specifically `apt-get install -t trusty mozc-server`, but the issue is rather the same as for installing it from zesty: although it installs the correct libprotobuf as a dependency, it reports "This program ... is not compatible with the installed version (2.6.1)" of the Protocol Buffer runtime library (the one that was previously installed and is still installed alongside the one newly installed for `uim-mozc`). I’m afraid one needs to completely switch to zesty or make a custom build using the available libprotobuf version (if that ever works).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it finally worked on the same Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial):

1. add `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `sudo apt-get update` (**do not** upgrade)
2. `sudo apt-get install uim-mozc uim-gtk2.0 uim-xim` (`uim-gtk3` had some runtime libprotobuf incompatibility issues and uim-xim seems necessary to actually change input method)
3. start `uim-xim` and `uim-toolbar-gtk` or it should also run on reboot
4. remove that zesty entry from `/etc/apt/sources.list` again